# Angular - How to validate maxlength in ngx-intl-tel-input

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, ngx-international-phone-number

I am using the *ngx-intl-tel-input* package in my Angular-12 project multistep. I have this code:

Component:

```
import {
  SearchCountryField,
  CountryISO,
  PhoneNumberFormat
} from 'ngx-intl-tel-input';

export class SignupCompanyComponent implements OnInit {
  isLinear = true;
  isLoading = false;
  companySetupForm!: FormGroup;
  companyForm!: FormGroup;
  idForm!: FormGroup;
  SearchCountryField = SearchCountryField;
  CountryISO = CountryISO;
  preferredCountries: CountryISO[] = [CountryISO.UnitedStates, CountryISO.UnitedKingdom];

  changePreferredCountries() {
    this.preferredCountries = [CountryISO.India, CountryISO.Canada];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.companyForm = this.fb.group({
      companyName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(100)]],
      mobileNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
    }, {
      updateOn: "blur"
    });
    this.idForm = this.fb.group({
      registrationNumber: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(100)]],
    });
  }

  get fc() {
    return this.companyForm.controls;
  };
  get fi() {
    return this.idForm.controls;
  };

  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;

    const formCompanyData = this.companyForm.getRawValue();
    const formIdData = this.idForm.getRawValue();

    const data = {
      companyName: formCompanyData.companyName,
      mobileNumber: formCompanyData.mobileNumber,
      registrationNumber: formCompanyData.registrationNumber,
    };

    this.spinnerService.show();
    const header = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

    this.isLoading = true;
    return this.api.post('signup', data, header)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.tokenHandler(data);
        });
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper labelPosition="bottom">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="companyForm">
    <form [formGroup]="companyForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel matStepperIcon="phone">Company Info</ng-template>

      <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="mobileNumber">Mobile Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <div class="input-group mb-4">
            <ngx-intl-tel-input [cssClass]="'form-control mb-4'" [preferredCountries]="preferredCountries" [enableAutoCountrySelect]="false" [enablePlaceholder]="true" [searchCountryFlag]="true" [searchCountryField]="[SearchCountryField.Iso2, SearchCountryField.Name]"
              [selectFirstCountry]="false" [selectedCountryISO]="CountryISO.India" [maxlength]="15" [phoneValidation]="true" [separateDialCode]="true" name="mobileNumber" formControlName="mobileNumber">
            </ngx-intl-tel-input>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.mobileNumber.touched && fc.mobileNumber.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fc.mobileNumber.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Mobile Number is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.mobileNumber.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Mobile Number cannot be more than 15 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Company Name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>}
          <input type="text" formControlName="companyName" placeholder="Company Name" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.touched && fc.companyName.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('minlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name cannot be less than 3 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fc.companyName.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Name cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext [disabled]="companyForm.status != 'VALID'">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step [stepControl]="idForm">
    <form [formGroup]="idForm">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Company ID</ng-template>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="registration_number">Registration Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
          <input type="text" formControlName="registrationNumber" placeholder="Registration Number" class="form-control" required/>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.touched && fi.registrationNumber.invalid">
          <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.hasError('required')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Reg. No. is required!
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="fi.registrationNumber.hasError('maxlength')">
            <div class="text-danger">
              Company Reg. No. cannot be more than 100 characters!
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button mat-raised-button color="black" matStepperPrevious>Back</button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="success" [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">
                        <span *ngIf="isLoading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                          Submit
                      </button> &nbsp;
        <button mat-raised-button color="warn" (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
      </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

When the user enters data, I expect input validation. But I have these two (2) issues on the `mobileNumber` in the *ngx-intl-tel-input*:

1. It allows the users to enter more than 15 `maxlength`.
2. Whenever the `maxlength` is greater than 15, it disables the Next button without indicating the error and this brings confusion.

How do I resolve these?

Thanks.

Comment: `fc.mobileNumber.touched && fu.mobileNumber.invalid`. Is it typo error? Should be `fc` instead of `fu`?

Comment: @YongShun - Its typo. I changed it to fc, but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like `maxLength` validation is not supported by `ngx-mat-intl-tel-input`.

Instead,

You have to use **`validatePhoneNumber`** to determine whether the inputted text is a valid phone number. As [Official documentation (Refer to Example section)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-intl-tel-input) provides the example:

> If you want to show the sample number for the country selected or errors , use mat-hint anf mat-error as

```
<mat-error *ngIf="f.form.controls['phone']?.errors?.validatePhoneNumber">Invalid Number</mat-error>
```

And the **Next button is disabled** is due to the **inputted phone number doesn't fulfill the phone number format for the selected country.**

---

### SOLUTION

The HTML for `validatePhoneNumber` validation should be as below:

> signup-company.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="fc.mobileNumber.touched && fc.mobileNumber.invalid">
  ...
  <div *ngIf="fc.mobileNumber.hasError('validatePhoneNumber')">
    <div class="text-danger">
      Invalid Phone Number!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And remember to remove `Validators.maxLength(100)` from `mobileNumber` field as it is no longer needed.

> signup-company.component.ts

```js
this.companyForm = this.fb.group(
{
  companyName: [
  '',
  [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(3),
    Validators.maxLength(100)
  ]],
  mobileNumber: ['', [
    Validators.required
  ]]
},
{
  updateOn: 'blur'
});
```

[Sample solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d8ksmt?file=src/app/signup-company/signup-company.component.html)